# Cv2 saying "Camera found" even though its not

Tags: python, opencv, video, webcam

I'm trying to make a program that automatically stars showing video if it detects input. But it still thinks video input is there even though the camera isn't even connected, It should show video as soon as i connect the exteral camera, but it dosent.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

ImageSource = 1
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource) 

def testDevice(source): #this is to make the auto show feature.
while (True):
    if (cap1.isOpened):
      print('got video output')
      break


testDevice(ImageSource)

if (cap1.isOpened):
while(cap1.isOpened):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap1.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```